# Mercurial: enable git subrepo

Tags: git, configuration, mercurial

Recently this behavior was disabled by default. The message prompts you to check the help page but it's not helpful, at least it didn't help me.

```
 "subrepos"
    ----------

    This section contains options that control the behavior of the
    subrepositories feature. See also 'hg help subrepos'.

    Security note: auditing in Mercurial is known to be insufficient to
    prevent clone-time code execution with carefully constructed Git subrepos.
    It is unknown if a similar detect is present in Subversion subrepos. Both
    Git and Subversion subrepos are disabled by default out of security
    concerns. These subrepo types can be enabled using the respective options
    below.

    "allowed"
        Whether subrepositories are allowed in the working directory.

        When false, commands involving subrepositories (like 'hg update') will
        fail for all subrepository types. (default: true)

    "hg:allowed"
        Whether Mercurial subrepositories are allowed in the working
        directory. This option only has an effect if "subrepos.allowed" is
        true. (default: true)

    "git:allowed"
        Whether Git subrepositories are allowed in the working directory. This
        option only has an effect if "subrepos.allowed" is true.

        See the security note above before enabling Git subrepos. (default:
        false)

    "svn:allowed"
        Whether Subversion subrepositories are allowed in the working
        directory. This option only has an effect if "subrepos.allowed" is
        true.

        See the security note above before enabling Subversion subrepos.
        (default: false)
```

I assumed it was adding the following to the project's hgrc:

```
[subrepos]
git:allowed
```

But it gives a parsing error. Does anyone know the right format? And also, why they decided to disable this? Each time I checkout this project I'll have to make this change?

Comment: The syntax should be `git:allowed = true`. I have not tried it, but compare to, e.g., section `[diff]` setting `git = true`. You can set it in your personal `.hgrc` if you are not concerned about the security issues.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your `.hgrc` file, you must add:

```
[subrepos]
git:allowed = true
```

Comment: This can be also enabled just for a single repository by editing `.hg/hgrc`.

Answer (score 4):

I used the following in my `~/.hgrc` config and verified `allowed` and `git:allowed` both enable and disable functionality as expected.

```
[subrepos]
allowed = True
hg:allowed = True
git:allowed = True
svn:allowed = True
```

Comment: this is the best answer

Answer (score 1):

In a Debian 8 docker container, Mercurial version 3.1.2, mercurial stopped working for us after migrating repos and subrepos to phabricator.  It reported:

```
abort: subrepo type git not allowed
(see 'hg help config.subrepos' for details)
```

First of all, to see the help it is just

```
hg help subrepos
```

But that isn't useful.  The syntax suggested above for .hgrc did not work for us.  However this did:

```
[subrepos]
allowed = hg git
```

Comment: This helped my company out a lot. Thank you so much!