# After distro upgrade, mercurial won't commit git subrepo

Tags: git, mercurial, mercurial-subrepos, subrepos

I've recently upgraded from Devuan ASCII to Devuan Beowulf (i.e. Debian Stretch to Debian Buster). I think I've installed all relevant mercurial-related packages; but when I try to commit a mercurial repo with a git subrepo, it tells me:

```
abort: git subrepos not allowed
(see 'hg help config.subrepos' for details)
```

Why is this happening and how should I fix it?

Notes:

- Current mercurial version is 4.8.2, previous was 4.0.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49577952/mercurial-enable-git-subrepo - each type of subrepo must be enabled explicitly

Comment: [subrepos]
hg:allowed = True
git:allowed = True
svn:allowed = True